# Enter text onclick in php filterinput

Tags: php, jquery

Code to input text in php filterinput on button click... not working.  Is it possible?  The idea is for the user to click a button (or a link - i will reformat the button later) that will fill in a jquery sharepoint filter.  The Jquery filter auto filters the sharepoint list... but i want a link to do this (without postback)...   best solution i could come up with was the html form webpart and a jquery script that autofilters the list onkeyup.  but i want a link on the page to input text into the filter...   (See code)  not working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script>
function changeText() {
    x = document.getElementById("filterInput");
    x.options[x.selectedIndex].text = "Melon";
}
</script>

</head>


<body>

<input type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="Test">

    <input id="filterInput" type="text" name="search" size="80" style="color:silver" value="Click here and start typing your search criteria..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Click here and start typing your search criteria...'){this.value='';}">

</body>

</html>
```